# how to get hostname in subject of Grafana's 9.0 alert mail?

Tags: go, grafana

I tried to use templates for alert mails in Grafana 9.0.
I get the hostname of alerting hosts in my alert mails by adding `{{ $values.B0.Labels.host }}` into summary of the alert rule. It works fine if i don't use any template.

However, i am using a template for the subject of my alert mails and need to access the hostname in the template.

My template looks like this:

```
{{ define "xxx.email.subject" }}
{{ if .Alerts.Firing -}}[{{toUpper .Status}}:{{ len .Alerts.Firing }}] {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }}
{{ end }}
{{ if .Alerts.Resolved -}}[{{ .Status}}:{{ len .Alerts.Resolved }}]
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

I tried adding `{{ .CommonLabels.hostname }}` and other different keywords with no avail.
Can someone tell me how i can access the hostname directly in the template?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my alert was not connected with a panel correctly.
If you connect an alert with a panel then you can access the host label with `{{ .CommonLabels.host }}`. Of course you should have a setup with defined labels for that.